# Making sense of git submodule status output

Tags: git

I am having trouble understanding the output of `git submodule status`. I think it's because I don't use tags very often.

I added a submodule to a Git repository (you can replicate this locally really easily using the 3 `git` commands directly below):

```
/ $ git init
/ $ git submodule add https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git
Cloning into 'bootstrap'...
## Output abridged ##
/ $ git submodule status
93694898838b479d2806c53c827847f724312bcc bootstrap (v2.3.1-2965-g9369489)    
/ $ cd bootstrap/
bootstrap/ $ git rev-parse HEAD
93694898838b479d2806c53c827847f724312bcc
```

I checked out `v3.0.0`:

```
bootstrap/ $ git checkout v3.0.0
Note: checking out 'v3.0.0'.
## Tells me about the detached HEAD ##
HEAD is now at e8a1df5... remove dumb validation reports
bootstrap/ $ cd ..
/ $ git commit -a -m 'Added submodule and changed its checked out commit'
```

The output of `git submodule status`:

```
/ $ git submodule status
e8a1df5f060bf7e6631554648e0abde150aedbe4 bootstrap (v2.3.1-2765-ge8a1df5)
```

The commit that's referenced  (`e8a1df5`) makes sense to me, but the tag is confusing. `man git-submodule` says thats each line of `git submodule status` output is:

> the SHA-1 of the currently checked out commit for each submodule, along with the submodule path and the output of git describe for the SHA-1.

So the output of `git describe e8a1df5f060bf7e6631554648e0abde150aedbe4` is `(v2.3.1-2765-ge8a1df5)`? But I just checked out `v3.0.0`?!

Anyway, `man git-describe` says this:

> The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit. If the tag points to the commit, then only the tag is shown. Otherwise, it suffixes the tag name with the number of additional commits on top of the tagged object and the abbreviated object name of the most recent commit.

So, applying this knowledge to `(v2.3.1-2765-ge8a1df5)` from the `git submodule status` output I received above:

- "`v2.3.1`" must be the most recent tag reachable from `e8a1df5`
- "2765" must be the number of commits on top of "`v.2.3.1`"
- and "`e8a1df5`" must be the abbreviated object name of the most recent commit (see `man gitrevisions` re: the `g` prefix)

But this doesn't make sense to me. Why is `v2.3.1` plus 2765 commits shown instead of `v3.0.0`? After all, I did check out `v3.0.0`, and:

```
bootstrap/ $ git tag --contains `git rev-parse HEAD`
v3.0.0
```

How can I find out why `git describe` decided that `v2.3.1` is the most recent reachable tag? What's going on here?

Comment: What version of Git? Ensure you’re using the latest in case this is a bug that’s been fixed.

Comment: `--version` reports `git version 1.7.9.5`. This is the latest version in Ubuntu 12.04. You think this may be a bug?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Sweet Dijkstra code in your profile. I saw this book yesterday: http://www.amazon.com/What-Computers-Still-Cant-Artificial/dp/0262540673, and was totally bummed out. Didn't read any of the book, but judging it exclusively by the title I thought "man, someone's missing the point."

Comment: It certainly seems wrong enough to possibly be. You can get the most recent version by using the official [Git PPA](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Haven't had a chance to try upgrading Git, but I did make an edit above that answers this a bit. Weird stuff. Looks more and more like a bug?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: I just tested with version 1.8.4 and it's the same deal. I check out `v3.0.0` in the submodule, and `git submodule status` tells me `v2.3.1-2765-ge8a1df5`. The commit is correct (I still don't understand the `g` prefix) but the tag (`v2.3.1`) doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [By default (without --all or --tags) git describe only shows annotated tags.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html#_description)

So v3.0.0 being a lightweight tag would produce this behavior.

Comment: Might be nice to link/reference what you’re quoting from.

Comment: Ugh. Looks like we (I, or the OP) will need a custom command replacing `git submodule status`, that calls `git describe` in a more useful fashion.

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE be careful, lightweight tags are mutable.